# Access main page elements from a separate page (PageSlide)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jquery PageSlide plugin as a menu on my site (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) This opens a separate page on the side of the main page to act as a menu of sorts. But I was wondering how I could access the main pages elements from this side bar. For example I have an Iframe I want to manipulate from the side page, but I don't know how to accomplish this because they are on separate pages! Thanks, any help is appricated.

Comment: The short answer is: You can't. For security reasons you can't manipulate a page from another iframe using JS. Tell us what are you trying to do so we can see if there is an alternative.

Comment: Well I'm using the plugin to make a cool slidible menu on my site, like the basic example on the plugin site or the mobile version of facebook.

Comment: @SunnyD: I don't have a clue what you're trying to do. And why the hell would you use a plugin that uses iFrames?...

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I frankly don't know how to be any more specific. As I said above I am trying to use the plugin to make a side menu like the first example on the plugins site (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) or on the mobile version of facebook. And I am using the plugin because I like the style and effect of the menus it    makes. But using iframes is a downside of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are evil IMHO and should be avoided as much as possible. As I mentioned in my comment earlier, you can not run JS from an Iframe that can act on the main page. That would be a VERY scary world if that was possible.

If you want to have menu that slides from the side like many current mobile apps.

**I would recommend considering those options:**

1. You can do that with pure jQuery with no extra plugins. There are many resources online and one is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753024/how-to-make-a-sliding-menu-similar-to-the-facebook-mobile-side-menu-with-html-cs) discussing this in detail as well as a simple demo for it.
2. You can look for plugins that can help you with what you are trying to do, with a quick search, I came across [this](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). But I am sure there is more.

Comment: The plugin you found fixes my problem. I am trying to make a mobile menu that looks like that. Thanks!